# Попытался сделать что то на подобие композиции не вышло, почему не работает код?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Попытался сделать что-то на подобие композиции, не вышло. Почему не работает код и что нужно сделать чтобы он заработал? Ещё новичок в этом и хочу разобраться.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(f'{val}' * 10, self)
        v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def create_file(self):
        self.tab = Widget(self.val)
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        str = f"NEW {self.val}"
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), str)
        self.val += 1

    def close_tab(self, ind):
        self.tabWidget.removeTab(ind)

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.app = App()
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.app.close_tab)
        self.action_2.triggered.connect(self.app.create_file)
        self.val = 0

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(381, 265)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 361, 201))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 381, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Файл"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Новый файл"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под композицией, что должна делать ваша программа и с какой проблемой вы столкнулись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не вникал в логику того, что вы сделали, а просто внес изменения чтобы не было ошибок. Если это подобие на композицию, пускай будет так.

Обратите внимание:

```
self.app = App(self)                  # + self
```

и

```
def __init__(self, parent):           # + parent
```

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(f'{val}' * 10, self)
        v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):                             # + parent
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent                                # +

    def create_file(self):
        self.tab = Widget(self.parent.val)                  # self.parent
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.parent.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")          # self.parent
        _str = f"NEW {self.parent.val}"                     # self.parent
        self.parent.tabWidget.setTabText(self.parent.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _str) # self.parent
        self.parent.val += 1                                # self.parent

    def close_tab(self, ind):
        self.parent.tabWidget.removeTab(ind)

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.val = 0                                                    # +
        self.app = App(self)                                            # + self
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.app.close_tab)
        self.action_2.triggered.connect(self.app.create_file)
#        self.val = 0                                                   # -

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(381, 265)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 361, 201))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 381, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Файл"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Новый файл"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если class App() не является дочерним классом class Ui_MainWindow() то да, это можно назвать композицией