# Будет ли считаться наследником класс, который использует родительские компоненты, с помощью parent?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, parent

Будет ли считаться ***`наследником`*** класс, который использует родительские компоненты, с помощью `parent`?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос... Покажите свой код

Comment: Нет, если нет наследование виджета

Comment: Код в ответе на вопрос по ссылке
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177288/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4

Comment: @ILOVEPYTHON ответ написан в тексте вопроса по ссылке. Это композиция, а не наследование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае нет. Вы можете проверить применив `parent()`.

> QObject *QObject::parent() const
>
> Возвращает указатель на родительский объект.

> void QObject::setParent(QObject *parent)
>
> Делает объект дочерним по отношению к родителю.

> const QObjectList &QObject::children() const
>
> Возвращает список дочерних объектов.

Если вам надо сделать объект дочерним, вы можете сделать:

```
...
def __init__(self, parent):                             
    super().__init__()
    self.setParent(parent)
...
```

или так:

```
...
def __init__(self, parent):                             
    super().__init__(parent)    
...
```

Посмотрите на принты, которые я вставил.
Также обратите ВНИМАНИЕ, что я заменил `self.parent = parent`  на `self._parent = parent`,
чтобы распечатать `self.parent()`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(f'{val}' * 10, self)
        v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):                             
        super().__init__()
#        super().__init__(parent)
#        self.setParent(parent)
        self._parent = parent                                       # !!! _parent

    def create_file(self):
        self.tab = Widget(self._parent.val)   
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self._parent.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        _str = f"NEW {self._parent.val}"     
        self._parent.tabWidget.setTabText(self._parent.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _str)
        self._parent.val += 1                          

        print(f'\nApp: self -> {self}')                              # +++
        print(f'App: parent -> {self.parent()}')                     # +++
        print(f'App: children -> {self.children()}')                 # +++

    def close_tab(self, ind):
        self._parent.tabWidget.removeTab(ind)

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.val = 0                                                    
        self.app = App(self)                                          # + self
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.app.close_tab)
        self.action_2.triggered.connect(self.app.create_file)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(381, 265)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 361, 201))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 381, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Файл"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Новый файл"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    print(f'\nui:            -> {ui}')                                         # +++
    print(f'ui: parent     -> {ui.parent()}')                                  # +++
    print(f'\nui: children ->vvv :')
    print(*[ [obj.objectName(), obj] for obj in ui.children() ], sep='\n')     # +++ 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]